# Making a basic Java file server multi-threaded

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, runnable, serversocket

I've got a server which sends to its client the contents of a text file.

The 'server' package has a '**Main**' (takes in port no. from cmd line args and parses it), '**Server**' and a '**FileHandler**' class and I think I've got them in a way (using a threadpool) so that the server is able to serve concurrently to two clients.

Now I'm trying to build a CLI with options to start & stop the server. I'm looking to implement 2 threads, where one thread will listen for the input and another for the 'accept()' call.

My attempt at it so far has been to create a new class '**Commander.java**' and take in an *AtomicBoolean* in the constructor and then store it in the object to use as a flag for stopping the server thread.

I want the thread that is listening for the 'accept()' call to periodically check if a request has been made to stop - how can I do this with my 'Commander' class?

Including some code snippets (a.k.a. my attempt so far) for your better understanding:

```
class Server implements Runnable 
{
Socket sock;
ExecutorService executor;
private int port ;

public Server(int p) {
    port = p ;
    executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
}

public void startServer() {
ServerSocket s = new ServerSocket(port);
...
while (true)
{
    Socket temp = s.accept();
    sock = temp;
    executor.execute(new FileHandler(sock));
    // serveFile(temp) ;
}

public void run() {
    startServer();
}
}

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    while(true) {
        System.out.println("Main menu:\n" +
                       " 1 - Start server\n"+
                       " 2 - Stop Server\n"+
                       " 0 - Exit");
        int in = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());

        switch(in) {
            case 1: 
                // start server
                System.out.println("Starting server...");
                Thread th1 = new Thread(new Server(port));
                th1.start();
                System.out.println("Case continuity...");
                // server.startServer() ;
                break;
            case 2:
                // stop server
                System.out.println("Server stopped.\n");
                break;
            case 0:
                // exit
                System.exit(0);
                break;
            }
        }
     }
 }

class FileHandler implements Runnable {

Socket socket;

public FileHandler(Socket socket) {
    this.socket = socket;
}

private void serveFile() {
 ...code for serving file...
}


public void run() {
    serveFile();
}
}

public class Commander implements Runnable
{

 private AtomicBoolean bool;

 public Commander(AtomicBoolean bool) {
    this.bool = new AtomicBoolean(bool);
 }

 public boolean value() {
    return bool.get();
 }
```

Comment: Take a look at NIO and `Netty framework`.

Comment: You don't need another class, you don't need netty, try this: add a Boolean variable running outside the big loop, and change the big loop as while(running) {..}, in the loop, read the `action` (part of data in request) from your client, when action == SOME_VALUE, set running = false, then while() will end, after that, do cleanup.

Comment: @EricWang at class `Server` when inside the while loop, the thread will be blocked at `.accept()` until a connection (request) is received. so changing the boolean will not stop the app, because it's already inside the `while`. Theorically: it will change boolean `running` to `false` but this will not stop the server until one more request is received.

Comment: @Yazan I said, the `read the action from client`, which means it's already accepted, then set the `running` variable, this is before the next loop start, so it should work, I guess, right?

Comment: OP, I just noticed that  you have 2 class, 1 is `Main`, 1 is `Server`, each has a `while()` loop, why bother, you need only 1 class, and 1 `while()` loop, I think.

Comment: @EricWang this can be right in case there is a parameters in the request, i.e there is an `action`, it could be just a establish connection, and response is dumped immediately.

Comment: @Yazan I said it's a request very clearly in previous comment.

Comment: @EricWang the point is, it's not about what you have said, it's about what the case is, i mean what is the OP requirements

Comment: @Yazan You didn't understand my first comment before you reply it, that's all what I mean.

Comment: Not really looking for frameworks guys. I'm doing this more as an exercise as I'm new to concurrency in Java and wanted to play around with it. Just as a sidenote, my requirement was basically for two clients to request a file from the server and for the server to serve them concurrently. I also wanted an option in the server package where the server could be stopped and started again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @Kayaman [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36278483/3604083):

**A- At your Server class:**

1- let `ServerSocket` be a class member scope:

```
ServerSocket s = new ServerSocket(port);
```

2- add a method `shutdown()`:

```
public void shutdown(){
    try{
        s.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStacktrace();
    }
}
```

3- add `try/catch` to handle socket close (do a clean shutdown):

```
while (true)
{
    try{
        Socket temp = s.accept();
        sock = temp;
        executor.execute(new FileHandler(sock));
        // serveFile(temp) ;
    }catch(SocketException ex){
        doAcleanShutdown();
    }
}
```

**B- In your Main class:**

1- let `Server` instance be class member scope

```
Server myServer = new Server(port);
```

2- In switch (`case 1:`) use `myServer` instance

```
case 1: 
    // start server
    System.out.println("Starting server...");
    Thread th1 = new Thread(myServer);
    th1.start();
    System.out.println("Case continuity...");
    // server.startServer() ;
    break;
```

3- to stop the server, `case 2:`

```
case 2:
    // stop server
    myServer.shutdown();
    System.out.println("Server stopped.\n");
    break;
```

Comment: Very neat solution - appreciate your effort.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is wrong. The thread that's blocked on `accept()` shouldn't do anything but wait and start new threads (or submit new tasks) as connections are made.

When you want to shut down the server, call `close()` on the `ServerSocket` (from a different thread of course). The thread blocked on `accept()` will throw a `SocketException` and you can then clean up and exit.

Comment: The Thread management is done using executors. The FileHandler is a runnable executed in a thread of the executors threadpool.

Comment: @pdem That wasn't really the point of the answer. The point was calling `close()`.

Comment: @Kayaman can i post an answer (with code snippets) based on this answer?

Comment: @Yazan If it's correct, knock yourself out. I don't own any exclusive rights to what I described :)

Comment: @Kayaman ok i get it. Then maybe you could remove the first sentence, the second sentence is just a perfect "simple fast" solution.